# How can i have a single MySQL connection for whole project in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a static mysql connection method for my project, connection doesn't make again if thread is now alive, but there are a problem, when we use of ajax, each ajax request get a separate connection, because ajaxes program consider as outside of current program flow.
I tried to save connection object as a session, even i serialized that, but i got error when try to use of it again.

it's my code:

```
public static function DBConnect(){

    if(!self::$conn)
    {
        self::$conn = $link = mysqli_connect(_dbHost_,_dbUser_,_dbPass_,_dbName_);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            echo 'Could not select database ' ._dbName_ .' '. mysqli_error($link);
            exit;
        }
        mysqli_query($link,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        //var_dump(self::$conn);
        return self::$conn; 
    }
    else
        return self::$conn;

}
```

So is anyone to idea for give me only one connection whole project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible the easy way, as the connection is usually closed when the request ends, and AJAX requests are seperate requests.

But you could have a look at persistent connections, which are explained at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php and built up by prefixing your hostname with `p:`. This keeps the connection open over multiple requests

Comment: now i use of persistent connection according your advise, but i see new things, in the past my connection was about 200 and the processes was about 20, but now the connection is about 15 and the proccess is up to 200-250, So what is process number limit? and Does this condition make any problem?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it.

> each ajax request get a separate connection

this is how php is meant to work